# Why doesn't cin have specifier format or ampersand like scanf?

Tags: c++, c

Having

```
int a;
```

in C++, why doesn't

```
cin >> a;
```

need ampersand like

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

in C ?

Comment: What makes you think it should? Besides, C++ is smart enough to know the type of `i`.

Comment: Because C++ is not C.

Comment: `cin << i;` is completely wrong anyways! Never compiles.

Comment: @walter Editing the question  radically in shape,  just to fit with your answer isn't such a good action. I'm going to roll that back again. Rather explain in your answer, what's wrong with `cin << i;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, so it is a typo cin >> i; Anyway, you don't have to answer my so call (vague) question if you don't want to. No need to be rude.

Comment: @tuyenle I never was rude, but telling you facts. Correction of typos are accepted, if you edit yourself. If that's done by others it just blurs what you're asking for, and renders possible answers useless. Take more efforts reviewing what you're posting here in future please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I put my best effort in to be as clear as possible. No need to belittle it. I made mistake sometime

Comment: @tuyenle If that's your _best efforts_ **good luck** for your future career.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Reccomend removing non-applicable   [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727946/why-doesnt-cin-have-specifier-format-or-ampersand-like-scanf/32728238#comment53299468_32727946)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, we have not only variables and pointers (as in C), but also *references*. On the calling side, passing a reference looks like passing a variable by value, but on the side of the function called, it actually receives not a copy, but a reference to the actual variable and hence can alter it. You can think of a reference like a pointer but without the need to de-reference.

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&i, some_type&x);
```

declares an operator that takes a reference to a `std::istream` and another to `some_type` and returns the `std::istream` reference. With this declaration you can now

```
some_type x;
std::cin >> x;   // calls above operator, pasing x by reference
```

---

Passing by reference and passing by pointer are very similar, and may actually produce identical code:

```
void f1(int*x) { *x=2; }
void f2(int&x) { x=2; }

int a;
f1(&a);   // is equivalent 
f2(a);    // to this
```

The common wisdom in C++ is to pass variables that shall not be altered either by value (if they fit into a single register) or by `const` reference. Variables that may be altered by the function called can either be passed by (non-`const`) reference or by pointer, this is a matter of style: with the latter it is explicit at function call that the variable can be altered, while the former (passing by reference) requires one to look up the API of the function to find out whether one passes by value, reference, or `const` reference.

Comment: This is a bit incomplete - it explains only why we don't need `&x`.

Comment: @MSalters I thought that was the question. What else do you think was asked?

Comment: From the title: " Why doesn't cin have specifier format ... like scanf ?"

Answer (score 4):

`cin` and `i` are passed by reference to `operator >>` given it the ability to read and write `cin` and `i`.

As C has no true reference passing, `scanf("%d", &a);` code needs to pass the address of `a` for `scanf()` to write a value to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ use fundamentally different methods when passing arguments of varying type.

In C, a single function like `scanf(const char* pattern, ...)` can accept many different types of parameters. That's why it needs a `pattern` parameter where you tell it the actual types it has received. If you pass anything unexpected, you have a runtime issue.

In C++, a single function *name* may be implemented repeatedly for different types of parameters. This is called overloading. Each overloaded implementation will know exactly what it expects, and the compiler will assure that it only gets that type of values. If there's no matching overload, you have a compile-time error.

Another difference is that in C++, `cin >> i` is actually a function call of `operator>>`. In C, function calls all look like `functionName(argument)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanf in c++ , How ever still better to use cin. "cin>>"not "cin<<"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
          float x;
          scanf("%f",&x);
          printf("%.1f",x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this actually answer the (not very clear) question? Rather explain what `cin >> x;` really does, and what reference parameters do in C++.